# Using require.js to collect and inline npm-installed modules into front end JS files

Tags: node.js, requirejs, gruntjs

I have a project and installed for example `underscore` and `marked` via `npm install`. When I launch `node` in my project root folder, I can `require` both with `var __ = require("underscore")`, similar for `marked`. This is how I use both libraries in my backend, if needed. Now I want to write a `myscript.js` which is delivered to the browser, it's referenced for example in my `index.html` file. In this script, I want to use both mentioned libraries as well.

For this to work, I think there are two methods:

1. inline the required files (I think I prefer this)
2. copy the required `js` files into a separate directory, and use `require.js` in the browser.

In neither case I want to point a program to where the libs are found, similar to `node`, which knows what to do by just saying `require("lib")`.

My questions are:

- Did I understand this correctly?
- Is `grunt-contrib-requirejs` exactly the the thing I need to automate this process?
- Can someone provide me with a snippet of code or point me to a blog post or something? I think I lost the overview, I found [the documentation](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) but many things are confusing.

Here is what I have so far:

Configuration for my Grunt task:

```
requirejs: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: "./",
      name: "src/main.js",
      out: "build/result.js"
    }
  }
}
```

My `main.js`:

```
var _ = require("underscore")

function foo(values)
{
    _.find(values, function(value){ return false; });
}
```

The result:

```
function foo(e){_.find(e,function(e){return!1})}var _=require("underscore");define("src/main.js",function(){});
```

... not exactly what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not answer my original question, I found out that using node modules is not exactly the way to go for frontend stuff, I found `bower`. Anyway, this whole thing is very frustrating.

Bower allows me to install required packages, and then there are modules for grunt which allow the JS files either to be "plugged" into the HTML document within a special section, or to be concatenated into one file. Bower-ready modules should ship with a `bower.json` file. This reliefes me fron the work of manually collecting all needed js files from the `node_modules` folder like I was afraid of in the question.